# Twitter bootstrap modal fade this.$backdrop is null error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a simple modal fade in effect. I have tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/Wc8PB/2/

And it works with no error.

But when I upload a test file on my server I get error in firefox: this.$backdrop is null

See here: http://mydirectory.altervista.org/prove/modal.html

What iI'm missing?

Comment: it works for me on FF. However there is a not closed <div> (before </body>)

Comment: Have you tried to click on add comment in modal? which version of FF?

Comment: i don't see any add comment button.